# CSS, create dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I dont know whether this can be possible by pure css. Please check my example.

http://jsfiddle.net/fantill/72xjU/

I want when hover level 2 of the menu will display Level 3 with `'inline'` like level 1, and same time display all Level 4 menu below each level 3 with `'block'`like level 2.

```
-------------------------------------------
|      MENU                               |
|      Level 1                            |
-------------------------------------------
| Level2|           Level 3  Inline       |
|       |----------------------------------
|       | Level4  | Level4 | Level4|Level4|
--------|         |        |       |      |
        |         |        |       |      |
        |----------------------------------
```

Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/4CGwe/1/

markup should respect this scheme:

```
#BLABLA > ul > li > a
#BLABLA > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a
```

(every `<LI>` should contain `<A>` and optionally `<UL>`)

here is the CSS:

```
    #BLABLA ul
        {list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;display:none;}
    #BLABLA li
        {position:relative;}
    #BLABLA a
        {border:2px red outset;padding:10px 30px;display:block;}

    /* by default only the first level menu is visible */
    #BLABLA > ul
        {display:block;}

    /* by default hovering a item will try to show its own sub-menu */
    #BLABLA li:hover > ul
        {display:block;}

    /* any submenu (2,3,4 level) is absolute */
    #BLABLA ul ul
        {position:absolute;}

    /* FIRST LEVEL MENU */
    #BLABLA > ul > li
        {float:left;}
    #BLABLA > ul > li > a
        {background:orange;}

    /* SECOND LEVEL MENU */
    #BLABLA > ul > li > ul
        {top:100%;left:0;}
    #BLABLA > ul > li > ul > li > a
        {background:pink;}

    /* THIRD LEVEL MENU */
    #BLABLA > ul > li > ul > li > ul
        {left:100%;top:0;width:900px;} /* sadly here you have to set manually a huge width */
    #BLABLA > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li
        {float:left;}
    #BLABLA > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a
        {background:gold;}  

    /* FOURTH LEVEL MENU */
    #BLABLA > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a
        {background:lightblue;}
```

PS: tell me if you are interested to alternatives to set width:900px